# Why bulk collect into clause is limiting the size of nested table in pl/sql

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g, oracle11g, plsqldeveloper

```
declare
   type yy is table of t12.name%type;
   y yy:=yy();
   n number:=1;
begin
   y.extend(10);
   select name bulk collect into y from t12;
   --select name into y(5) from t12 where id=1; If i uncomment this line it gives error
   for i in (select name from t12)
   loop
      dbms_output.put_line(y(n));
      n:=n+1;
   end loop;
end;
```

Comment: There are only 4 rows in table t12 I have alloted 10 blocks using y.extend(10) .Why am i not able to access y(5)

Comment: comment the line `select name bulk collect` and uncomment the currently commented line... the error should be gone...

Comment: are noooooooo....thats where the prob lies..I know it will work...but the thing is...with bulk collect..what is it doing with my nested table..why cant i add more elements to this table after using bulk collect...

Comment: you can add more elements... what you try is accessing element at index 5 wihtout checking first whether that element even exists... the `builk collect` replaces your nested table - it creates a new one.

Comment: Now thats what I called concept building...I was also thinking like that..but i was not confident..but now..everything is crystal clear..tnx anyways....

Comment: One more thing...Why dont bulk collect do the same thing to index-by table I mean it doesnt replaces it...

Comment: "why" is usually a question for the implementor (i.e. Oracle)... I suspect it does something similar but that would need some sample code to check...

Comment: declare
type yy is table of t12.name%type index by binary_integer;
y yy;
n number:=1;
begin
select name bulk collect into y from t12;
select name into y(5) from t12 where id=1;
for i in 1..5
loop
dbms_output.put_line(y(n));
n:=n+1;
end loop;
end;

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4459/discussion-between-tarun-and-yahia)

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4459/discussion-between-tarun-and-yahia
I m here

Comment: in case you cant come on chat..above is the code...sry for no new lines...but in this case...there was no as such replacement i noticed

Answer (score 1):

Could you test without initializing `y` first ? Nested tables are not supposed to be initialized with bulk collect. Then you can add elements with `extend`.

```
declare
  type yy is table of t12.name%type;
  y yy;
begin
  select name bulk collect into y from t12;
end;
```

Comment: your code will give error..static...referencing uninitialized collection...If u see properly I have initialized table y using constructor...

Comment: And I also did y.extend(10)..so actually i m not initializing it using bulk collect I am just assigning some values

Comment: It won't raise an error. Please see the example 12-16 in [BULK COLLECT Clause](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/tuning.htm#i49139). You are initializing it with `y yy:=yy();`. Bulk collect is not supposed to be used like you do.